# Acquiring Long Lasting Facebook Token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Through Facebook's PHP SDK getting started [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0) it takes you through the process of initializing your app, creating a Login URL and then handling the call back data and doing a simple query.

In the documentation it says you can skip the initializing process providing an access token from 'some other means'.

```
$session = new FacebookSession('access token here');
```

Due to the lack of documentation I'm struggling on how I would define a scope before creating the login URL and then use the call back data to extract the access token.

Comment: Do you have to use the PHP SDK? Why not just go the easy way and use the JavaScript SDK for login? Although, it is hard to tell what you want to achieve, to be honest. Long Lasting Token? What for exactly? There are different ones.

Comment: if you followed the getting started guide you should already be getting long-lived tokens - are you not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/) will help you get started with using the Facebook PHP SDK to log a user in.

Basically, you need to setup your application first and use the `FacebookRedirectLoginHelper` to create the login URL:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'xxx','yyy' );

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://yourwebsite.com/app/' );

// show login url, scope is array of permissions
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( [ 'email', 'user_friends' ] ) . '">Login</a>';
```